# IE9-IE10 - can't click absolute positioned element

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, less

I have this search field:

[image]

The right 'x' is clearing the text. it works fine on all browsers except for IE9/10.

From what i can see, once the icon is positioned above the input, it is no longer clickable, like the input is covering it (although it is visible). If i move the icon a bit to the right so it is not positioned on the input, it functions as expected.

I tried changing the z-index but with no success.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="capbSearchPanel" data-bind="with: searchVM">
    <div class="capbWrapper">
        <a href="#" class="capbBtn capbBtnCancel cafeLeft">Cancel</a>
        <div class="capbSearchInputWrapper cafeLeft">
            <span class="capbIcon capbClearTextIcon"></span>
            <span class="capbIcon capbSearchIcon"></span>
            <input  type="search" class="capbSearchInput"  autofocus="true" placeholder="Search For Anything..."/>
        </div>
        <a href="#"><span class="capbIcon cafeLeft"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**less:**

```
/* SEARCH FIELD*/
.capbSearchInputWrapper{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

    input{
        width: 100%;
        height: 31px;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 0px 26px 0 27px;
        border: solid 1px #c0c0c0;

        //iPads (landscape) -----------
        @media only screen
        and (min-device-width : 768px)
        and (max-device-width : 1024px)
        {
            padding-top: 5px;
        }
    }

    .capbIcon{
        line-height: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: 24px;
        margin-top: -12px;

        //iPads (landscape) -----------
        @media only screen
        and (min-device-width : 768px)
        and (max-device-width : 1024px)
        {
            margin-top: -13px;
        }

    }
    .capbSearchIcon{
        // content: url('@{capbImgPath}/icon_search_323232.svg');
        left: 5px;
        &:before{
            height: 25px;
            content: url('@{capbImgPath}/icon_search_323232.svg');  
        }       
    }

    .capbClearTextIcon{
        right: 5px;
        z-index: 10;
        &:before{
            height: 25px;   
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the `content` for the `.capbClearTextIcon`? I don't see it listed, and the `:before` needs content to work right.

Comment: yeah, sorry, the content is defined in a different file (icons.less) anyway, all the icons are showing properly as you can see, the only problem is it's not clickable

Comment: Granted the `content` being there (based off the image), from the code provided here it seems as though it should work. Can you produce a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) reproducing the problem (I attempted to, but could not seem to reproduce the issue)?

Answer (score 0):

Beacause you are setting a hight value on the "before" pseudo-elment of .capbClearTextIcon I am guessing that the icon is also defined through that pseudo element?
If that is true, did you try to put the icon in the real span and not it's pseudo elements?
Like this:

```
.capbClearTextIcon {
    background-image: url('@{capbImgPath}/icon_close_323232.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
```